# How to fetch dropdown value from List in selenium Webdriver by using java

Tags: java, html, sql, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to consider list value as a dropdown value?

How to select Edit Drop down value from List...

```
<div class="nice-select demoBasic" tabindex="0">
    <span class="current">Please select</span>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="option" data-value="1">Edit</li>
        <li class="option" data-value="2">Delete</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `By.cssSelector()` to get all options in list as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//First click on select div 
WebElement select = wait.until(ExepectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.nice-select.demoBasic")));
select.click();

//Not get all nested options 
List<WebElement> options = wait.until(ExepectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(select, By.cssSelector("ul.list li.option")));

//Now iterate to fetch all options and select edit option
for(WebElement option : options)
{
  if(option.getText().equals("Edit"))
  {
      option.click();
  }
}
```

Or you can select an option on the basis of text in one line using `By.xpath()` as below :-

```
wait.until(ExepectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//li[text() = 'Edit']"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Saurabh Gaur

Comment: @SaurabhGupta No problem, try it and let me know if it helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

I got it solution ...

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div/ul/li[1]")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(4000);
```

Comment: It's not the good solution, you are using xpath with element position which not stable.. and using `Thread.sleep() ` is also not a best way..you should try using `WebDriverWait` instead..